# How to execute console commands on google appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to execute a java program within another java program on `appengine`. For that i must access the java compiler and jvm on `appengine`. How i can do that? Is there any way to do this?

On my local machine i can do this in following way

```
//To compile java program
Process p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac filename.java");

//To run it by calling class having main function
Process p2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java class_name");

//To access the output given by second process
BufferedReader ou = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
```

My exact question is can we do this on `appengine` backend?

Comment: Not it's not possible as per Martin's answer. I hate using the word "should", however you should read the docs on the appengine runtime and it's restrictions.  This is a basic feature of appengine and anyone embarking on development for this platform should ("there I go again") understand what they are dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [Compute Engine](https://developers.google.com/compute/) instead of AppEngine to compile and run your own processes on Google Cloud Platform.  The code that runs on AppEngine is always compiled before deployment, and the executable that runs is always the Jetty web application server, not your main process.

Edit: Android client apps should use http or https requests to access the Compute Engine app.  Because of the way Compute Engine works, you would need to script its Debian or CentOS package installation commands to install the software on which you app will depend.